# html comment indicator in AJAX return

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Im trying to do an AJAX get call and it keeps returning a comment and 2 new lines before returning my intended value to the initial call. In my index.php the code is...

```
var iden = $(this).parent('li').attr('rel');
$.get("pullArtists.php", {idenp: iden}, function(data){
alert(data);
});
```

and my code for "pullArtists.php after connecting to the db is...

```
if( $_REQUEST["idenp"] )
 {$iden = $_REQUEST['idenp'];
  $qry = "SELECT * FROM artists WHERE entity_id = ".$iden;
  $result = mysql_query($qry);
  $name = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
  if (!$result) 
     die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error()); 
  echo json_encode($name);
 }
```

the alert from the top code section will return this when i activate the $.get

```
<!---->

{"entity_type":"node","bundle":"artist",
"entity_id":"485","revision_id":"485","field_artist_al   pha_name_value":"Acconci
Vito","field_artist_alpha_name_format":null,"published":"0"}
```

Anyone have experience with this?

Comment: It's coming from your php. Are you sure you don't have some additional php include in pullArtists.php that could be adding that comment?

Comment: @MingMan Have you checked any extra lines @ the beginning for that particular `entity_id`?

Comment: Your code is very vulnerable to sql injection.

Comment: Can you post the entire `pullArtists.php`

Comment: Kevin here is the entire code for pullArtists.php: http://imgur.com/V2wNOge  -- John, what do you mean "at the beginning"?, -- Filip, i will worry about security later

Comment: @FilipGórny How can a `rel` attribute vulnerise to SQL Injection?

Comment: @dollarvar He is using `$_REQUEST` variable in SQL query without escaping, which means anyone can do pretty much everything with his database.

Comment: Always use prepared statements when passing dynamic data to the database. Best protection against SQL injection.

Comment: @IgorJerosimić Yeah, if someone knew he would have to use `idenp`. ;)

Comment: We would then only need the `config.php`, MingMan!

Comment: @dollarvar But `idenp` is visible right there from client side script, and nevertheless you should not base your security on assumptions that someone doesn't know name of your variable.

Comment: @IgorJerosimić Ok, ok, you are right. You could guess that idenp is used. I prefer prepared statements of course btw. And, btw, `mysql` driver is deprecated: http://de1.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

Comment: Dollarvar, it was in the config file, for some reason i thought that would have nothing to do with it.  I still dont understand why it does, but i got rid of it and it worked.  Thanks